# How do you load a Sound object in tinySound in visual studio code?

Tags: java, audio, visual-studio-code

Here is the example provided by the library **tinySound**
: https://github.com/finnkuusisto/TinySound/blob/master/example/TinySoundExample.java

I read the example and wrote the basic piece of code to test its functions :

```
TinySound.init();
Music forest = TinySound.loadMusic("absolutepath/day.ogg");
forest.play(true);
```

Upon execution I get :

```
Unable to find resource /absolutepath/day.ogg!
```

I work with visual studio code and was wondering why java couldn't find the file, even though the path put in is absolute and the resource is in the workspace.

Here is the reduced project tree structure :

```
/Project
 |------/ResourceMusic-----/forest----day.ogg
 |------/lib
 |------/bin
 |------/src----Main.java (location of my test of tinySound)
```

Comment: Can you share the exact file structure, showing what folder is holding day.ogg and what folder is holding your equivalent to TinySoundExample?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me. I have updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tinkering around a bit, I found an alternative to absolute paths for tinySound in vsc.

It goes as follows :

```
File aFilesound = new File("relativePath/file.wav");
Music fileMusic = TinySound.loadMusic(aFilesound);
fileMusic.play();
```

This way, the resource folder doesn't need to be in the src folder for the music to work.

Answer (score 0):

To confirm the file structure you gave, I'm assuming the following two files.

```
Project/src/Main.java
Project/ResourceMusic/forest/day.ogg
```

I would try the following:

```
  Music forest = TinySound.loadMusic("ResourceMusic/forest/day.ogg");
```

But I'm not 100% sure this will work.

Here is my best understanding of what is going on.

The literal class `TinySound` holds the following code for reading the resource (after doing multiple verifications):

```
URL url = TinySound.class.getResource(name);
```

Now, if `name` were a relative address, the file would be expected to be located relative to the folder in which the `TinySound` class itself resides. But since a "/" is prepended (which can be seen by looking at the source), the *absolute* address is used. Thus, the top folder of the project source is used as the root address.

For example, I have an Eclipse project called "ScratchPad". In it is a package, called "dodads" with the following class:

```
package dodads;

import java.net.URL;

public class TestAbsoluteAddressing
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TestAbsoluteAddressing taa = new TestAbsoluteAddressing();
        taa.doAbsTest();
    }

    private void doAbsTest()
    {
        URL url = this.getClass().getResource("myAudio.wav");
        URL url2 = this.getClass().getResource("/myAudio.wav");
    
        if (url != null) System.out.println("relative found");
        else System.out.println("relative not found");
    
        if (url2 != null) System.out.println("absolute found");
        else System.out.println("absolute not found");
    }
}
```

The following file structure elicits "relative found" and "absolute not found":

```
ScratchPad/src/doodads/TestAbsoluteAddressing.java
ScratchPad/src/doodads/myAudio.wav
```

The following file structure elicits "relative not found" and "absolute found":

```
ScratchPad/src/doodads/TestAbsoluteAddressing.java
ScratchPad/src/myAudio.wav
```

Now, the worrisome part is that the file structure you gave me doesn't include a "src" file folder. So I'm not entirely sure the addressing I gave you will work.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. This does work as you pointed out if you put the resource files in the src folder. However other problems occurred afterward such as classes being not imported for some obscure reasons. I tried putting the resource folder outside of the src folder. Then, the relative and absolute path both failed unfortunately.